# Jquery UI dialog box.. dialog box content loading on main page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, modal-dialog

I am activating a dialog box like so:

```
   $('a#addNew').click(function(){
   $('#popup').dialog({
       minWidth:  700,
       title:     'Select a product item'
   });
});

<div id="popup" style="color:#fff; background:#000; width:650px;">
    blah blah blah blah
</div>
```

thats all well and good.. but the dialog box (#popup) is actually showing up on my page until i click #addNew, in which case it disappears and transfers to the actual dialog box.  I only want the user to see that information when they click on #addNew.  I dont want it to be sitting on the page.  What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div id="popup" style="color:#fff; background:#000; width:650px; display:none;">
    blah blah blah blah
</div>
```

You need to hide this div while it is on the page. The dialog will then unhide it and display it for you.

Comment: I'd take it a step further; instead of inline styles, move this to the CSS stylesheet. But this is the right idea.

Comment: oh yeah.. duh.  i didnt know it would auto unhide it for me.

Comment: yeah i know inline styles are frowned upon.  just easy right now while im building the page.

Comment: Beware, it's easy now, but when your page is nearly complete and you look at all the inline styles you now have to refactor into a stylesheet you may be kicking yourself for not just doing it from the start.

Answer (score 0):

using css add
display:none;

or using JQuery add
$('#popup').hide();

Answer (score 0):

It's on the main page *because that's where you put it!*

You need to hide the div (css - `display: none`)  when its first created.